# SimpleXML failing on Lenovo P90

Tags: android, android-proguard, simple-framework

We have problem with using SimpleXml and Proguards obfuscation on one (for now we found just one) specific device. It is Lenovo P90.

On every other device, application is working good so far. Also when I turn obfuscation off, app works fine.

Log from device:

```
 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 873: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 871: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 872: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/Reader;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 W/dalvikvm: WARNING: could not find annotation member b in Lorg/simpleframework/xml/ElementList;
 E/dalvikvm: Failed creating annotation element (m=0x4f29bc50 n=0x4f29bc30 a=0x0 r=0x0)
 E/KBMB:SimpleRestJob2: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation
retrofit.RetrofitError: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
      at $Proxy18.a(Native Method)
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:41)
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:28)
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2$1.a(UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2.java:45)
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.job.SimpleRestJob2.run(SimpleRestJob2.java:34)
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.RestJobExecutor$1.c(RestJobExecutor.java:37)
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.BaseJob.a(BaseJob.java:108)
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.a(JobHolder.java:60)
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.executor.JobConsumerExecutor$JobConsumer.run(JobConsumerExecutor.java:201)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

  Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation
      at retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter.fromBody(SimpleXMLConverter.java:50)
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) 
      at $Proxy18.a(Native Method) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:41) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:28) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2$1.a(UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2.java:45) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.job.SimpleRestJob2.run(SimpleRestJob2.java:34) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.RestJobExecutor$1.c(RestJobExecutor.java:37) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.BaseJob.a(BaseJob.java:108) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.a(JobHolder.java:60) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.executor.JobConsumerExecutor$JobConsumer.run(JobConsumerExecutor.java:201) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation
      at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:201)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.FieldDetail.<init>(FieldDetail.java:57)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.fields(DetailScanner.java:428)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.scan(DetailScanner.java:367)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.<init>(DetailScanner.java:140)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailExtractor.getDetail(DetailExtractor.java:107)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getDetail(Support.java:278)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getDetail(Support.java:271)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ScannerFactory.getInstance(ScannerFactory.java:76)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getScanner(Support.java:357)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getScanner(Source.java:271)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getSchema(Source.java:317)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:198)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
      at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
      at retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter.fromBody(SimpleXMLConverter.java:48)
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367) 
      at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) 
      at $Proxy18.a(Native Method) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:41) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.contacts.dataaccess.ContactsProcessorImpl.a(ContactsProcessorImpl.java:28) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2$1.a(UnsecuredRestProcessorImpl2.java:45) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.job.SimpleRestJob2.run(SimpleRestJob2.java:34) 
      at cz.kb.mba.core.shared.rest.dataaccess.RestJobExecutor$1.c(RestJobExecutor.java:37) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.BaseJob.a(BaseJob.java:108) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.a(JobHolder.java:60) 
      at com.path.android.jobqueue.executor.JobConsumerExecutor$JobConsumer.run(JobConsumerExecutor.java:201) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here are some important parts of project/build configuration
SimpleXml import:

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Proguard configuration for simplexml
(I googled more rules but nothing worked so far):

```
# simplexml
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamReader*
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; }
```